# .size not giving accurate file size

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are using .size in angularjs to get file size but it is not giving accurate result.

Actually .size gives value in bytes so in below code we have **maxUploadSize = 100000000**; (**100000000 byte = 100 MB**)

When I am uploading a file of size 97657kb(97mb) but .size returns **100000249bytes**(which greater than 100mb).

Code:

```
function (files) {
            angular.forEach(files, function (value, key) {
                alert(value.size);
                //validate the size of file
                if (value.size > maxUploadSize)
                {
                    alert("File: " + value.name + " is too large, it must be smaller than " + byteToMb +"Mb");
                    toastr.error("File: " + value.name + " is too large, it must be smaller than " + byteToMb + "Mb");
                }
 })      
        }
```

Comment: 976,567 KiB = 1,000,005 kB. Are you mixing units? [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte)

Comment: no, I mean MB only not MiB

Comment: Either way, you have it backwards. It's not AngularJS that's wrong. And there's not enough information to determine why your number is wrong.

Comment: ok, Pardon me for that. We have function where we are doing file.size wich gives size value. What do you want me to share , code snippet?

Comment: No idea, but again, it's `976567` you need to explain. And you need to provide the actual value from `.size`, which isn't `100000` for a 100 MB file.

Comment: but ... `976567kb` is 10 TIMES `97mb`

Comment: your code would make it easier to know what it is you're doing - also, check your maths, as 976567KB is over 900MB (unless you mean 976567 kilo**bits**

Comment: yep, my bad. extra 6 I added in number by mistake, I updated in question.

Comment: 97657KiB is 100,000,768 BYTES - what is the size, in BYTES of the file - or with the reverse calculation of `100000249 / 1024 = 97656.493KiB` - so, yes, you are mixing units

Comment: Uploaded file is of 97657kilobyte but .size returns 100000249bytes

Comment: I suspect the file inspector gives you a size in MiB, but your back-end validation library checks against MB (which just shows why making MiB was a mistake)

Comment: yes, 97657*1024 > 100000000 - you're uploading a file, the filesystem is telling you the size in KiB/MiB not KB/MB (as they do, without the `i` - just because KiB/MiB came well after windows 95, and Microsoft are Microsoft, and don't change without a good reason to do so) - simply change the limit to `104857600 bytes` - then you can upload 100MiB all day long

Comment: As I shared above, Uploaded file is of 97657kilobyte(97657000 byte) but .size returns 100000249bytes.

It is not returning KiB/MiB for sure, it is byte.

Comment: _"As I shared above, Uploaded file is of 97657kilobyte(97657000 byte)"_ - and those values were determined where and how, exactly? Are you actually getting both values shown - or just one of them, and _you_ determined the other one from that?

Comment: 97657kilobyte I can see on local system where I have tis file stored and 97657000 byte is I determined it from kb value.